# Citing footnote in mla

Tags: citations, mla

There's a footnote in an annotated novel I'm reading, and I want to use what's said in that footnote in my essay. I'm not sure how to cite the footnote within my essay, and on my works cited page. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's what the footnote says if that helps: See G.M.S. Chivers, *A Pocket Companion to French and English Dancing* (London, 1821): "quote that I'm using" (36).

Answer (score 1):

In MLA, you cite the page as you normally would and add "n" and the number of the footnote, e.g. "Smith 123n6" for footnote number 6 on page 123.

Source: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/18/

Comment: Okay, so just to make sure I'm doing it right, would it look like this: (Burney 27n2) with Burney being the name of the author, not of what the footnotes is. And for my works cited page, what would I do? Sorry for the trouble, I just don't want to lose marks on this

Comment: Ah, the footnote contains a citation? Look under "Citing indirect sources" on this page: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/2/ What you do is something like: `Chivers says: "Quote that you are using." (qtd. in Burney 27n2)` Then list both sources in the bibliography.